# How to send message header properties through IBM MQ remote queue with RFH?

Tags: java, properties, header, ibm-mq

I need to push a message into a remote Queue sending some header properties.
In my side I'm using IBM MQ v9 and I must not use the MQRFH2, just the 'native' MQ header (I'm not sure if it is possible).
But when I'm pull the message I can no see any of the properties.

```
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.JMSProducer;

import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQDestination;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

public class MessageSender {

    public void sendMessage() throws JMSException {
        JMSContext context = createJMSContext();
        JMSProducer producer = context.createProducer();
        Destination destination = context.createQueue("queue:///" + queueName);
        System.out.println("destination: " + destination);
        MQDestination mqDestination = (MQDestination) destination;
        // the header properties to be added
        mqDestination.setStringProperty("KEY1", "VALUE1");
        mqDestination.setStringProperty("KEY2", "VALUE2");
        mqDestination.setStringProperty("KEY3", "VALUE3");
        // WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ - static final int WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ
        // WMQ_TARGET_CLIENT property value. Target is an MQ application (RFH2 will be excluded).
        mqDestination.setTargetClient(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);
        System.out.println("mqDestination: " + mqDestination);
        String message = "mymessage";
        producer.send(mqDestination, message);
    }

    private JMSContext createJMSContext() {
        JMSContext context = null;
        try {
            JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
            JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();
            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, false);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "hostname");
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "channel");
            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, 1411);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "queueManager");
            context = cf.createContext();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return context;
    }

}
```

Comment: What technique / API are you using to try to read the properties on the consumer side?

Comment: You are already setting WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ as the TARGETCLIENT. This ensures messages your applications sends will not have RFH2 headers. What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

This code:-

```
mqDestination.setTargetClient(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);
```

is stripping the message properties off before the message is sent.

You say that you want to use the 'native header' and not 'MQRFH2' but the two are fully interchangeable. There is no one or the other, it is just how the message properties are presented to the receiver of the message depending on how they are capable of consuming them.

If you put messages properties and the receiver asks for them in RFH2 then that is what they will get.

If you build the correctly formed RFH2 header and the receiver asks for message properties then that is what they will get.

Remove the above mentioned line from your application and your message properties will flow to the receiver.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Morag's comment, people get confused over terminology.  An MQRFH2 message is the same as saying JMS message.

- An MQRFH2 (JMS) message can have message properties
- A regular (native) MQ message does not contain message properties

From a high-level, an MQRFH2 (JMS) message looks like:

```
[MQMD][MQRFH2]message payload
```

From a high-level, regular (native) MQ message looks like:

```
[MQMD]message payload
```

Comment: To be clear - even when you go nowhere near JMS - you can still have message properties and you can either build them with the native MQ API calls - MQSETMP etc, or you can build an MQRFH2 header with folders yourself. Both have exactly the same end result to the recipient application. To suggest an MQRFH2 message is somehow a JMS thing is perhaps confusing. JMS is one of many users of MQRFH2 headers.

Comment: @MoragHughson - true.  I use trying to keep it simple (KIS) for newbies.  :)